# Mongo db query return partial contents of a field based on a condition

Tags: mongodb

I'm just wondering if it's possible to run a query to grab only a partial of a certain field based on a condition. For example my data set looks like:

```
"Name":"John",
"History":[ 
    {
        "speed" : 5,
        "type" : "walking"
    }, 
    {
        "speed" : 6,
        "type" : "walking"
    }, 
    {
        "speed" : 7,
        "type" : "walking"
    }
]
```

I want to run a query like:

```
db.getCollection('membermodel').find({
    "Name":"John"
}, {
    "Name":"1",
    "History":"1",
    //specify field condition here 
    "History.speed":{$gt:6}
});
```

will give me a result only containing the data which its speed is greater than 6:

```
"Name":"John",
"History":[ 
    {
        "speed" : 7,
        "type" : "walking"
    }
]
```

Thank you very much in advance.
Mars

Comment: yes, it is possible. Was this question?

Comment: great! Can you please let me know which commend shall I use? I've been reading the documentation for a few hours now:( Thank you!

Comment: You have the gt in the wrong place. Should be something like -     "Name":"John", History : {$eleMatch : speed.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection). See the `$elemMatch` or positional `$` examples for a single match and the `.aggregate()` examples for multiple matches.

Comment: @gpullen Thank you for your reply. That still return the full History array, I just want to return a partial set of "History"

Answer (score 3):

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"Name":"John"},{"Name":1, "History":{$elemMatch :{"speed":{$gt:6}}}});
```

The `$elemMatch` operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

Answer (score 0):

For partial result use below query:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"History.speed":7},{_id: 0, 'History.type.$': 1})
```

This will give only those **History** objects which will pass your criterion.

Comment: Criteria looks wrong here as compared to the question asked by the OP as this will only match things where the value is "exactly" 7. Also there is a marked duplicate here long before your reply, which contains only "one" of the many possible answers listed there.